# Android keyboard on hold

Tags: java, android, triggers, keyboard, onkeydown

i've been trying to create an "onHold" action on the enter key of the keyboard.

```
searchField.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
 @Override
 public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  searchField.setText(searchField.getText().toString().replace("\n", ""));
 if((CounterRunning)&&(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP  ) && (keyCode  == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
 {
   CounterRunning = false;
   counter.cancel();
    AddItem();

}
if((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN  ) && (keyCode  == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
{
   CounterRunning = true;
   counter.start();
}
}});
 public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer{

     public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
         super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
         }
         @Override
         public void onFinish() {
             CounterRunning = false;
                 AskForDate();
         }
         @Override
         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

         }
}
```

i want the user to run `AddItem()` on click and run `AskForDate()` if the user hold on the enter key.
but the action `KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN` is only triggering when i remove the finger from the keyboard, am i missing something?
 tested on android 2.3.7 (CM7.2) and android 4.0.4 (CM9), both with default softkeyboard

Comment: My guess is that since Android can have many different software keyboards, not all of them support all the actions properly and thus you cannot reliably create an onHold action that always works. I hope someone proves me wrong, though.

Comment: can you elaborate your question more, as what exactly are you looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

[onKeyLongPress event](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.Callback.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29)

try the upper one, it says you must call **startTracking** in your listener

so your code should be like

```
if((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN  ) && (keyCode  == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
{
   event.startTracking();
}
```

and since *Activity* subclasses *KeyEvent.Callback* you can directly call your **AskForDate()** from there.

Comment: can you elaborate a little more?